# How to uncomment every line of a file

Tags: emacs

I'm unsure what happened, but I must've hit some keys and saved - I do not recall this occurring, but on opening my file I found every line was individually commented out. for example:

/* printf("blahblah\n"); */

has happened to every line in the file except for one function.

How did this happen, and how can I undo this quickly? There are hundreds of lines so undoing this manually may take more than an hour.

Comment: The right answer here is to just use uncomment commands, as others have said.  But the general problem of some how messing up a file and accidentally saving it can be mitigated with Emacs's builtin backup system.  See the wiki (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory) for how to set it up sanely, and use the backup-walker package to look through backups easily.

Answer (score 4):

You had probably managed to type <kbd>M-;</kbd> (`comment-dwim`) with the whole buffer marked.

You can try marking the currently-commented region and using <kbd>M-;</kbd> again to uncomment it.

If it was literally every line, then <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> is the standard sequence to mark the *whole* buffer; but in this case you should be careful not to include that one uncommented function in the region, otherwise Emacs may try to comment everything again.

i.e. Set the mark with <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> at one end of the commented lines, then move point to the other end -- <kbd>M-<</kbd> and <kbd>M-></kbd> skip to either end of the buffer, if that helps -- such that the region is entirely commented, and then type <kbd>M-;</kbd> (or alternatively <kbd>M-x</kbd> `uncomment-region`).

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the text to be uncommented.  To select all of the text in the buffer you can use `C-x h`.
2. Use `C-u M-x comment-region` to **un**comment.